# serve-favicon npm package not working with express

Tags: node.js, express, openshift, favicon

I have a node.js server up and running as expected on openshift, but I cannot seem to get the favicon to show up.  I have tried the exact code on the serve-favicon npm package github page with no success.  This is piece of my server.js code:

```
#!/bin/env node

var express = require('express');
var fs      = require('fs');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');

var SampleApp = function() {

  //  Scope.
  var self = this;

  self.initializeServer = function() {
    self.createRoutes();
    self.app = express();

    self.app.configure(function () {
        //Use to define static pages in directory
        self.app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/css'));
        self.app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/js'));
        self.app.use('/images', express.static(__dirname + '/images'));
        self.app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/images/favicon.ico'));
    });

    //  Add handlers for the app (from the routes).
    for (var r in self.routes) {
        self.app.get(r, self.routes[r]);
  }
};
```

Why is this not working?? I tried refreshing my browser cache and all those tricks too, and it still doesn't show up.  Also, there are no server error messages either.

Comment: favicons seem to be absurdly sticky. I use the same module and had changed my favicon at one point. With chrome I had to actually load the favicon URL directly and refresh it in order to get the cache busted.

Comment: Yup, tried that trick too @AndrewLavers  No success though :(